# My calendar has a name?

Tags: iphone, calendar

So, this is crazy and I cannot find how to solve the problem.  My calendar has a title to it and I can't get rid of it!  Instead of the date and year it shows a sushi restaurant name: 29 Heisei
How do I get that to go away?  Please!!!

Desperate in West Lafayette!
Kev

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Of course the world revolves around 29 Heisei...

Answer (score 1):

1. Tap Calendars at the bottom of the screen to show the list of calendars.
2. Tap the **i** icon on the right of the calendar with the name you'd like to change.
3. Tap the name of the calendar to edit it.
4. Enter a new name for the calendar, then tap Done.